# rails 4 spree app doesn't show fontawesome icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, font-awesome, spree

I have a Spree Onlineshop based on Rails 4 with the bootstrap and fontawesome gems. Here an excerpt of the relevant codesnippets.

Gemfile:

```
# Twitter's Bootstrap 4
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha1'
# FontAwesome
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
# Enables Haml as the templating engine
gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.9'
```

application.scss:

```
 @import "bootstrap";
 @import "font-awesome-sprockets";
 @import "font-awesome";
```

and in my spree_application.html.haml:

```
.row
  .col-sm-2
    %p lorem ipsum
    = icon('pencil')
  .col-sm-10
    = yield
```

Everything works fine except that the fontawesome icons are not displaying.

In the Browser inspector i see that the icon('pencil') was converted to:

```
<i class="pencil"></i>
```

But in the browser the icon is not visible.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome requires a `fa` class and for the class of whichever icon you want to be prefixed by `fa-` as well. for example:

`<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>`

It might be worth building your own custom helper method, something like this:

```
def fa_icon(*args)
    content_tag :i, nil, class: (args.map{|arg| "fa " + "fa-#{arg.to_s.gsub('_','-')}" })
end
```